# Problems to serialize property (getter and setter) from a model using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to use a property (including setter) from my model in a Serializer, but apparently, the setter is never called.

models.py

```
class Awesome(models.Model):
    _value = models.TextField()
    def set_value(self, value):
        self._value = value
    def get_value(self):
        return self._value
    value = property(get_value, set_value)
```

serializers.py

```
class AwesomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Awesome
        fields = ('value',)
```

views.py

```
class AwesometViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Awesome.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AwesomeSerializer
```

On this scenario suggested above, when I make a GET the getter work fine, but when I make a POST the serializer doesn't call the setter.

What wrong I made?!

I am using following versions:

- python == 3.6.1
- Django == 1.11.2
- djangorestframework == 3.6.3

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly declare the `value` field on your serializer as a `serializers.CharField` ? I suspect DRF to create a ReadOnly serializer field for `value` as it is not a field on the model.

Comment: Yes Michael. I need to create explicitly the field like `value = serializers.CharField()` on Serializer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using [`ModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) which automatically creates read-write fields on the serializer based on the fields on the model. When it is not a field (a property or a method) and declared in `Meta.fields`, it defaults to a read only field.

Declaring it explicitly on the serializer will make it a RW field:

```
class AwesomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Awesome
        fields = ('value',)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using getter and setter in the serializer, you can create a custom Field class and override the functions:

- `to_representation` - instead the getter
- `to_internal_value` - instead the setter

For example:

```py
class ParamsField(serializers.JSONField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # Use the method `get_params` from the Awesome class
        return Awesome.get_params(obj)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Set the key `date` just for the example
        data["date"] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        return data


class AwesomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = ParamsField()

    class Meta:
        model = Awesome
        fields = ('value',)
```