# Django getter on model field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using **Django 2.x**

I have a model like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to change the value of balance on the GET request without changing the value in the database.

Like if it could be **@Property** field, the model will look like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    balance = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def balance(self):
        if balance:
           return balance
        return 0.15 * 50
```

But redeclaration is not allowed. How can I solve this issue?

Note: Field should be compatible with **ModelAdmin** and **DRF Serializer**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two ways. Either by using [a getter/setter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627034/5520354) and hide the actual table field. That would allow you to use `myobject.balance` like any regular field in the model, assigning to it with `myobject.balance = 123` and reading from it `print(myobject.balance)` etc.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    _balance = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def balance(self):
        if self._balance:
           return self._balance
        return 0.15 * 50

    @balance.setter
    def balance(self, value):
        self._balance = value
```

Using a leading `_` is the Python convention for "hidden" (private) fields.

A second and simpler way would be to simply use a `get_balance()` function, and not use a property.

```
    def get_balance(self):
        if self.balance:
           return self.balance
        return 0.15 * 50
```

Comment: imagine I already had the field, can I add getter/setter and change the field name without causing migrations? something like `_balance = models(db_field_name='balance')`

Comment: Disclaimer: cannot use the first method to make database entries using balance using a serializer in DRF

Answer (score 0):

To extend [C14L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5520354/c14l)'s answer, the getter/setter can be used in a DRF serializer but you have to declare it explicitly since the ModelSerializer introspection only look to fields (and not properties and methods) as it's explained by [Michael Rigoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4797469/michael-rigoni) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44720950) to [Problems to serialize property (getter and setter) from a model using Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44703213).

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    balance = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("name", "balance")
```