# django: simulate a flags Field using BInaryField

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

So I'm trying to simulate a flags field in Django (4.0 and Python3) the same way I could do in C or C++. It would look like this:

```
typedef enum{
    flagA = 0,
    flagB,
    flagC
} myFlags;
```

Having a `uint8` that by default is `00000000` and then depending on if the flags are on or off I'd do some bitwise operations to turn the three least significant bits to 1 or 0.

Now, I could do that in my model by simply declaring a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` or `BinaryField` and just creating some helper functions to manage all this logic.

Note that I **DO NOT NEED** to be able to query by this field. I just want to be able to store it in the DB and very occasionally modify it.

Since it's possible to extend the Fields, I was wondering if it would be cleaner to encapsulate all this logic inside a custom Field inheriting from BinaryField. But I'm not really sure how can I manipulate the Field value from my custom class.

```
class CustomBinaryField(models.BinaryField):
    description = "whatever"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 1
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

For instance, if I wanted to create a method inside `CustomBinaryField`, like the following, where the `myFlagsStr` contains a str representation of the enum.

```
def getActiveFlags(self):
    // For each bit which is set to 1 in the Binary value
    // add it to an array with it's name such as: [flagA, flagC]
    array = []
    if self.value & (1 << myFlags.flagA):
        array.append(myFlagsStr[flagA])
    if self.value & (1 << myFlags.flagB):
        array.append(myFlagsStr[flagB])
    if self.value & (1 << myFlags.flagC):
        array.append(myFlagsStr[flagC])
    return array
```

Not sure how to get the actual value stored in the DB to make this `if` comparisons.

Maybe mine is not the best approach to handle this, so I'm open to any suggestions you guys might have. But I think I could manage to do this the way I'm doing if I knew how to get the actual binary value from the DB from my functions.

I have seen there is a library https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield that handles this but it limits to using only PostgreSQL and also, as mentioned before, I don't really need to filter by these flags, so something more simpler will do too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in django common approach for building such functionalities is using [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield). It presumes that data is stored in the related table, which, I believe, is not very what you want.

The second opportunity is to use [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) which also isn't suitable for you since you don't want your solution to be limited to PostgreSQL.

If you're going to do this quickly and straightforward, you might use [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) and store the string or numeric IDs of your `Choices`. But if you are accustomed to C++, you're not gonna like it this way :)

> JSONField is supported on MariaDB 10.2.7+, MySQL 5.7.8+, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite (with the JSON1 extension enabled).

If so, you should look at [`SmallIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#smallintegerfield), it's stored as 16-bit signed int and use `getter-setter` approach to maintain it, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197488/12914274). The idea of implementation of the methods you suggested is right in general.

Good luck :)

Comment: I think I will go for the SmallIntegerField approach, thanks for the info. Anyways, I'm a bit curious about how to get the value of the Field when creating a CustomField that inherits from, for example, the IntegerField. In the case I wanted to create a function inside the custom Field class I mean. Any ideas on how to do that too?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, official docs about `CustomField` look quite intuitive and descriptive for me. Isn't [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects) what you need exactly about it?

Comment: One more idea for you. You can use [Flag enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intflag) in implementation.